# Angular router.navigate not working after 403 error

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

### Brief description

In my application, there are 100s courses and a user has access to few of them only. If he clicks on others, he gets 403 error. The moment he clicks on restricted course, from there all other navigation fails (even to the course he has access) and [router.navigate resolves to 'false'](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate). That is on click event, router.navigate does not work and emits NavigationCancel only.

Angular-7

---

### Pattern of error

1. I have search box and i use material input and [material autocomplete](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples) to list courses as user types.
2. search for course **Angular** (allowed), click on 1st result, **successfully navigates** to `/Course/499`
3. search for course **React** (restricted course), click on 1st result, so **show 403 error**. `/course/78` (403 error)
4. again search for **Angular**, click on 1st result, but **does not navigate now**.

---

### Code

*COURSE.COMP.HTML*

```html
<form class="search-form" *ngIf="cardsLoaded">
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Search courses</mat-label>
      <input
        matInput
        placeholder="eg. angular"
        name="search"
        autocomplete="off"
        #searchInput
        [formControl]="searchBox"
        [matAutocomplete]="auto"
      />
      <mat-autocomplete
        #auto="matAutocomplete"
        [displayWith]="displayFn"
        (optionSelected)="loadCourse($event.option.value.id)"  // FUNCTION TO NAVIGATE
      >
        <mat-option *ngIf="flag.searching">Searching Courses...</mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let course of list" [value]="course">
          <span class="option">
            <span
              class="{{ course.course_status }}"
              [innerHTML]="course.name | highlight: searchInput.value"
            ></span>
            <i> {{ course.course_status }} </i>
          </span>
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
      <mat-icon matSuffix>search</mat-icon>
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
```

**COURSE.COMP.TS**

```js
/**
 * Redirects user to the course page
 * @param id course id
 */
loadCourse(id: number) {
  console.log(`--------------LOADING COURSE (${id})---------------`); // i am getting correct courseId on every click
  this.router.navigate([`/Course/${id}`]).then(nav => {
    console.log('Yayy', nav); // true if navigation is successful
  }, err => {
    console.log('Navigation Failed', err) // when there's an error
    // this returns flase everytime, after clicking on a restricted course.
  });
}
```

**Guards**

```js
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private store: Store<State>
  ) {}

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authService.getProfile().pipe(
      map(
        // if success return true
        data => {
          this.store.dispatch(new fromCat.StoreProfile(data));
          return true;
        }
      ),
      // if failur return false, and redirect to login page
      catchError(err => {
        this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
        return of(false);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

**TokenInterceptor**

```js
export class TokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private snackbar: MatSnackBar,
    private store: Store<State>
  ) {}

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const token = this.authService.getApi();
    let clonedReq;

    return next.handle(clonedReq).pipe(
      // if api call returns any error, show details in console and redirect to appropriate page
      tap(
        (event: HttpEvent<any>) => {},
        (err: any) => {
          if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
            ////////// ERROR 404 - REDIRECT //////////
            if (err.status === 404) {
              console.log(
                "%cError in making HTTP request",
                "color: #FF0088; background: #222; font-size: 24px",
                err,
                clonedReq
              );
              this.router.navigate(["/notfound"]);
            }

            ////////// ERROR 403 - SNACKBAR //////////
            if (err.status === 403) {
              console.log('error');
              this.snackbar.open(`You do not have required permissions to perform the action. Please contact admin.`);
            }

            ////////// ERROR 401 - REDIRECT //////////
            if (err.status === 401) {
              this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
            }

            ////////// ERROR 400 - SNACKBAR //////////
            if (err.status === 400) {
              this.snackbar.open(`${err.error.error}`);
            }

            ////////// ERROR 500 - SNACKBAR //////////
            if (err.status === 500) {
              console.log(
                "%cError: 500 \n",
                "color: #FF0088; background: #222; font-size: 24px",
                err
              );
              this.snackbar.open(`${err.status} - ${err.error.error}`);
            }
          }
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

---

### DEBUGGING

- [ngZone](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15946#issuecomment-330892071) - not sure where to exactly keep this code piece
- checked router Events, it emits NavigationCancel everytime after user clicks on restricted course.

  ```
  this.router.events
  .pipe(filter(e => e instanceof RouterEvent))
  .subscribe((event) => {
      console.log('routerEvent =>', event);     
  });
  ```

---

### Screenshots

1. searching course with id=499, (could navigate)
   [image: navigate working fine]
2. search other course (restricted to user, id=78) and click on it. should not navigate as expected.
   [image: searching react]
3. Gives 403 error as expected. so fine till now
   [image: gives 403 error in console (expected)]
4. search and try navigating to course/499. could not nagivate.
   [image: router resolves to false]

---

Please suggest what could be the solution. I am not sure why router is behaving like this and how to force navigate it.

Comment: if you have the guard on the routes Please can you include it too.

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan I have added both token interceptor and guards. Can you have a look now?

Comment: Hello Raj, sorry for the delay, everything looks good, please can you explain how you block navigation on restricted courses?

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan No problem. I guess we both are in diff time zones. :-D. 
i am not blocking anything, i simply call `router.navigate('/course/${id}')` and the backend returns 403, so the NavigationCancel event is called from router.

Comment: and what are you doing after receiving 403 error on the course component?

Comment: I have created the stackblitz example please can you reproduce the issue what you have with fake courses data https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-28t4xw

Comment: > _and what are you doing after receiving 403 error on the course component?_


I just show [materialSnackbar](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview) with not-authorised message, in **TokenInterceptor**. You can find the code above.

Comment: > _can you reproduce the issue_

i"ll try, but not sure how to mimic 403 error in client side alone. As i get that from backend, when i call `router.navigate(/Course/78)`. This calls the api `api.domain.com/api/v1/courses/78.json` which sends me 403 error. I"ll let you know once i update stackoverflow.